# How Can i construct correct String in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am newbie in Clojure. I have following Expressions:

```
(= (__ "Dave") "Hello, Dave!")

(= (__ "Jenn") "Hello, Jenn!")

(= (__ "Rhea") "Hello, Rhea!")
```

In place of `__`, in all 3 places must be inserted same expression so that the equality check in all 3 cases are true. At this point i have come up with `str "Hello, "`. As i understand this should produce `"Hello, Dave" "Hello, Jenn" "Hello, Rhea"` How do i put `"!"` mark at the and of each string? (I can only "write" expression in place of `__`)

Thank you

Comment: Not so interesting answer is `(= (format "Hello, %s!" "Dave") "Hello, Dave!")`. but I don't know this is expected one.

Comment: @ymonad Thank you for the reply. I will have look at function format. But it certainly returns expected values

Comment: `(= (str "Hello, " "Dave" "!") "Hello, Dave!")` will work just fine as well :)

Comment: @JonasJohansson It certainly would work but only for the first problem (Dave) for others (Jenn, Rhea) it would not work. The idea is that it should work for all three

Comment: I see. Yeah, then make it a funcion like `(fn [name] (str "Hello, " name "!"))` or similar ;) But I see that there is a perfectly good answer below now. Happy Clojuring!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to drop a function into the place of `__`.

This function shall take a string `s` and shall return a string that is based on `s` so as to satisfy the three test cases.

A possible function is

```
(fn [s] (str "Hello, " s "!"))
```

which can written using Clojure syntactic sugar

```
#(str "Hello, " % "!"))
```

Thus

```
(= (#(str "Hello, " % "!") "Dave") "Hello, Dave!")
```

**Bonus: Using testing framework**

Clojure comes with a nice testing library, [clojure.test](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html) (I don't know why it is called an API, which would mean there is a component on the other side of the callable functions; it's just a library)

We can use the testing library for good effect:

```
(require '[clojure.test :as t]) ; make library visible

(def myfun (fn [s] (str "Hello, " s "!"))) ; our function as symbol myfun

(t/deftest test-stringmanip
   (t/is (= (myfun "Dave") "Hello, Dave!"))
   (t/is (= (myfun "Jenn") "Hello, Jenn!"))
   (t/is (= (myfun "Rhea") "Hello, Rhea!")))

(t/run-tests) ; do it!
```

Comment: API stands for Application Programming Interface. It is the interface you are meant to program against when using a component, such as a testing library. There's no implication that it's a client/server protocol.